# Why does one function end up in a symbol table and another one in the same file doesn't?

Tags: g++, ada, ghdl

I have an Ada source file with two functions:

```
procedure Ghdl_Psl_Assert_Failed
  (Str : Std_String_Ptr; Severity : Integer; Loc : Ghdl_Location_Ptr) is
begin
  Do_Report ("psl assertion", Str, "Assertion violation", Severity, Loc);
end Ghdl_Psl_Assert_Failed;
```

and

```
procedure Ghdl_Psl_Assume_Failed (Loc : Ghdl_Location_Ptr) is
begin
  Do_Report ("psl assumption", null, "Assumption violation",
             Error_Severity, Loc);
end Ghdl_Psl_Assume_Failed;
```

Both functions are exported to C-style symbols like so:

```
pragma Export (C, Ghdl_Psl_Assert_Failed, "__ghdl_psl_assert_failed");
pragma Export (C, Ghdl_Psl_Assume_Failed, "__ghdl_psl_assume_failed");
```

I build the file like this, at least for a test case, to show the problem:

```
g++ -c -Isrc/ghdl -g -I- src/ghdl/grt-lib.adb
```

When I use `nm` to look at the symbol table, I see that `__ghdl_psl_assert_failed` shows up, but `__ghdl_psl_assume_failed` does not.

It looks like somehow `Ghdl_Psl_Assume_Failed()` is being ignored by the compiler, but beyond that I don't have a clue.  I see the error show up in the full build of my project when another source file complains about not being able to find the function:

```
g++ -c -Isrc/ghdl/ -Isrc/clib -Isrc/zlib -Isrc/nuttx/nuttx/include -Isrc/nuttx/nuttx/uclibc/include/uClibc++ -Isrc/nuttx/nuttx/include/cxx -Isrc/nuttx/nuttx/include/nuttx/lib -Isrc/ghdl -g -I- -o /home/jon/controlix/bin/src/ghdl/ghdlrun.o src/ghdl/ghdlrun.adb
ghdlrun.adb:345:19: "Ghdl_Psl_Assume_Failed" not declared in "Lib"
gnatmake: "src/ghdl/ghdlrun.adb" compilation error
```

Any ideas?  It *looks* like this problem isn't present in the original GHDL build system, but I have to use my project's build system which doesn't use the standard GNAT project build system, which GHDL uses.

Answer (score 2):

Using your command line with a -v as user tgif suggests:

```
g++ -v -c -Isrc/ghdl -g -I- src/ghdl/grt-lib.adb`
```

reveals which gnat1 but doesn't have the error:

```
1155120@Macbook: !nm
nm grt-lib.o | more
0000000000002260 s EH_frame1
0000000000001b50 s GCC_except_table0
                 U __Unwind_Resume
00000000000006d0 T ___ghdl_assert_failed
0000000000000caa T ___ghdl_bound_check_failed
0000000000000ff0 T ___ghdl_check_stack_allocation
000000000000115a T ___ghdl_deallocate
0000000000000d5a T ___ghdl_direction_check_failed
0000000000000fac T ___ghdl_i32_exp
0000000000000fcc T ___ghdl_i64_exp
000000000000074e T ___ghdl_ieee_assert_failed
000000000000110e T ___ghdl_malloc
0000000000001126 T ___ghdl_malloc0
0000000000000254 T ___ghdl_memcpy
                 U ___ghdl_now
0000000000000a6a T ___ghdl_program_error
0000000000000806 T ___ghdl_psl_assert_failed
0000000000000884 T ___ghdl_psl_assume_failed
00000000000008f0 T ___ghdl_psl_cover
...
```

A bit of sleuthing shows your grt-lib.adb (on the left, from `https://sourceforge.net/p/controlix/code/ci/211711ec27e72ca23262433dfbebe9b905cecffd/tree/src/ghdl_grt/grt-lib.adb`) is out of date:

[image: comparison_grt-lib_adb.jpg]

and doesn't contain *procedure* `Ghdl_Psl_Assume_Failed`.

The date stamp shows 2019-08-11 while the right hand reference grt-lib.adb is from `GHDL 0.37-dev (v0.36-569-g5738c8a)` (downloaded 10 August 2019 and contains the procedure body, the .ads file likely out of date as well).

It looks like synchronizing `ghdl_grt` from a newer `ghdl/src/grt` is in order.

Support for PSL_Assume was added on 7 August (GMT+12) in ghdl master commit 0331772c.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `g++` instead of `gcc` ?  That's unusual.  Do you know which gnat1 is executed (try to compile using `-v`).